# Одинаковый URL для двух контроллеров?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть post запрос:

```
        $.post(document.location + 'Home/Res',
            function (data) {
                $('#n').empty().append("<h3>" + data.Name + "</h3><h5>" + data.Age + "</h5>");
            },
            'json');
```

В коде С#, есть два метода:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{   

[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Res()
    {
        return Json(new { Name = "2", Age = 34 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Ress()
    {
        return Json(new { Name = "1", Age = 34 });
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, что-бы URL оставался таким же mysite.com/Home/Res. Но, при запросе post брался ress() метод. Пытался решить проблему по этой статье https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing/#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes таким вот образом:

```
    [HttpPost("/Home/Res")]
    public JsonResult Ress()
    {
        return Json(new { Name = "1", Age = 34 });
    }
```

но компилятор говорит что у метода [HttpPost("/Home/Res")], нет конструктора с одним параметром. Скорей всего это связано что, эта статья написана для Core. 
Еще пытался делать так,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/Res")]
public JsonResult Ress()
{
    return Json(new { Name = "1", Age = 34 });
}
```

но выдает 404 ошибку.
Что мне нужно сделать, что бы url остался тем же, а запрос шел к нужному методу??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Res")]
public JsonResult Ress() {...}
```

Comment: Спасибо........)

Comment: @joraInTheSky, на здоровье)